# TinyButStrong htmlconv="no" dont print string which comes after doble quotes (" ") in tooltip

Tags: html, codeigniter, tinybutstrong

I have content which comes from database. I am using TBS library with codeigniter. I am displaying content with the 200 character limit. User can see full content with mouse hover on content as tool tip. But in tool tip the string which comes after double quotes(" ") are not displaying.

[image]

In above image only Hello freinds print.

**HTML Code  :**

```
<td><a class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip="<!--[blk4.tooltip;block=tr;comm;htmlconv=no;noerr]-->"><!--[blk4.tooltip;block=tr;comm;ope=max:200;]--></a></td>
```

If I remove htmlconv="no" from my HTML code then it print perfect but it prints br tag when line is break.

[image]

I have also tried this in controller

```
$string1=array("&nbsp;","<br />");
$string2=array(" ","/n");
$this->data['blk4'][]['tooltip']= str_replace($string1,string2,strip_tags($b['description']));
```

Any IDEA ??

Comment: I have solved my problem by replace this line in view page(HTML code)

<td><a class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip='<!--[blk4.tooltip;block=tr;comm;htmlconv=no;noerr]-->'><!--[blk4.tooltip;block=tr;comm;ope=max:200;]--></a></td>

I have change "" with '' in data-tooltip='' in above line

Thanx for you reply.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by replace this line in view page:

```
<td><a class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip='<!--[blk4.tooltip;block=tr;comm;htmlconv=no;noerr]-->'><!--[blk4.t‌​ooltip;block=tr;comm;ope=max:200;]--></a></td>
```

I have change " " with ' ' in data-tooltip=' ' in above line

Answer (score 1):

The htmlconv option will escape the quotation marks. Otherwise they will be included as-is (which is dangerous, and can lead to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerabilities).

When they are included, they simply break your HTML. Let's say you want this text in your tooltip:

```
Watch out for "quotation" marks
```

The html generated will then be broken like this:

```
<a ... data-tooltip="Watch out for "quotation" marks">...</a>
```

The syntax highlighting above shows you how a parser would think that your tooltip text ends when the first quotation mark occurs.

So **never** *ever* put user input without escaping it properly (for example by using `htmlconv`). Instead, strip out the `<br>` tags, maybe using [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$this->data['blk4'][]['tooltip'] = strip_tags($b['description']);
```

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your answer. I have used strip_tag but it not working in tool tip don't know why ??? I have also tried to replace br tag but in tool tip nothing is working. I can remove br tag only by using htmlconv="no" line but it cuts the words which comes after double quotes (" ") in tool tip ?? :(

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a valid content for the attribute value, you have to escape your string from XML/HTML entities and also from delimiters `"`. (They are other way to have an HTML valid content but is is quite more complicated.)

TBS does not give such a feature in native but you can change your data before the merging. You can also change it during the merging using an [`onformat`](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm_onformat) or [`ondata`](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_ondata) parameter.

Example of escaping the data :

```
$x = $this->data['blk4'][]['tooltip']
$x = strip_tags($x);
$x = str_replace('"', '', $x);
$this->data['blk4'][]['tooltip'] = $x;
```